# How to Increment values of an an array using a nested-loop

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops

So I need help. The problem is that an int `arr[5] = {0};`
I know the array has the values `{0,0,0,0,0}` filling the whole array. At the end of the code the array must have the values `{1,2,3,4,5}` inside it. To solve it must use a nested for loop. 
I have tried the following code
Sorry if there is an error in the way this question is formatted this is my first time and using mobile.

```
      int arr[5] = {0};

       for(int j = 1; j<6; j++)
       {

         for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
         {
           arr[i] = j;
         }
        }
```

Comment: This can easily be solved by replacing your entire block of code with `int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` so I'm curious if there's any extra information about why you need a loop? Let alone a NESTED loop? Are you sure a need a *nested* loop? This requirement (of nesting) seems strange even for contrived homework assignments. A single loop makes sense for a homework assignment, since that can be used to display the general concept of modifying a container with a loop index.

Comment: You tried the code. Then what? It all worked wonderfully and you had some ice cream to celebrate, right? :) To get debugging help, please give the expected *and actual* results. The more specific your question the better. (A bit of [debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on your part wouldn't hurt.) Preferably, create a [mre] so that others can copy the code and replicate your results.

Comment: @John The requirements do seem strange, but they might make more sense if there was also a requirement to avoid the use of the assignment operator, and instead use the increment operator. I could see nested loops where the inner loop's body is `arr[i]++;`. A bit roundabout, but it could help demonstrate, for example, how bubble sort works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the benefit of that but If you have to use nested for loop, the following is an option

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {0};

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {

        for(int i = 1; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            arr[j] = j+i;
        }
    }

    for(int i{};i<5;++i) std::cout << arr[i] << ", ";
}
```

Or like @JaMit comment suggests

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {0};

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < j+1; ++i)
        {
            arr[j]++;
        }
    }

    for(int i{};i<5;++i) std::cout << arr[i] << ", ";
}
```

Comment: @John Sorry, I didn't respond this is the question, my professor gave me to solve. They specifically asked for a nested for loop. I know it doesn't make sense to have a nested for loop. I even asked if I could use only one for loop but they said no.

Comment: @asis one commenter above suggested that you might be required to use the increment operator (`a[i]++`) instead of assignment (`a[i] = j`). Is that the case?

Comment: @John Also this is for a homework assignment which is why it's very frustrating that this is what they asked for.

Comment: @John The only information I was provided the question and that it had to use a nested for loop. I'm sorry if this is frustrating for you guys but this all they told me. Seriously sorry. I'll ask if I can use the increment operator instead. Thank you guys for the quick and polite answers despite the very frustrating question.

Comment: @AsisrusHerrera you can replace the incrementing operator `arr[j]++ ` by  `arr[j] = arr[j] + 1`.  they are equivalent .

Comment: @John I'll be asking my professor and should get an answer by tomorrow. I'll let you guys know what they say. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your professor means you should generate the final results using *only incrementation*. In other words, I'm guessing you're not allowed to *assign* values after the `int arr[5] = {0};` line (so an expression like `arr[i] = j;` is not allowed).

In that case, you could solve the problem as follows:

```cpp
int arr[5] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < 5; j++) {
    arr[j]++;
  }
}
```

Now we have only used incrementation and the final result is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.